# valid signing identity not found, provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode4, provisioning-profile

I know this question is used a lot, but I did not really find my case:

I Use Xcode 4.4.1, and for updating my provision profile/certificates, I just use refresh button under "LIbrary/Provisioning Profiles" and it works like a charm, gets updated, I checked my Keychain Access. And I can see the certificates.

But ALL my Provisioning Profiles in status are: "valid signing identity not found" except the one, which is  "IOS Team Provisioning" --> developer mode.

ALl distribution one are "valid signing identity not found" :(.

How can I fix this issue ?

1 More thing. I use the same certificate before on my OLD macbook and worked with no issue. Not I try to setup a new machine and this is what I get. DO you think it can be a conflict between 2 MACs? If yes, can you please help me how can I fix it (I have to remove from the old machine "developer mode" ?).

I really appreciate any help.

UPDATE:

Thanks to Alan Moore, I exported all Private key from old MAC. It for all al apps, the status is valid, but now is another issue, new apps.

Because I revoked the Distribution Certificate, all new apps are on new certificate and all new one are  "valid signing identity not found". :(

And because I revoked the old certificat, for all apps I have to renew the certificate, and once I do it, in my XCODE it becomes "valid signing identity not found".

It is  pretty weird issue, not even sure how can i fix this :(

Thank You!

Comment: Did you copy the private key over from your old mac?

Comment: No, where it is located ? and how can I do that ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You will have to do an export - import from your old mac.

**Export**:

1. In the XCode Organizer, select your team in the Teams section.
2. Click Export.
3. Specify a filename and a password, and click Save.`

The file produced contains the items you need to code sign apps,    including the provisioning profiles, certificates, and private keys    needed to install apps in development on a device.

**Import**:

1. In the XCode Organizer, select your team in the Teams section.
2. Click Import.
3. Select the file containing your code signing assets.
4. Enter the password for the file, and click Open.

(If you don’t see the Team section in the devices organizer:Drag the password-protected file that contains your code signing assets to the Xcode icon in the Dock.)

Comment: n0oitaf, it really helped, but for all apps which are in OLD distribution certificate.  But all new apps in new Distribution certificate do still have the same issue .  Do you have any ideas,

Comment: i think, i just added/removed a device in the profile in the provisioning-portal and this way it created a new one. not sure tho. Also maybe set checkmark at your certificate. Also the refresh button gives me quite some trash profiles, as it seems to get everything. you could also delete all profiles in organizer and then download them one by one manually an drop them in there.

Comment: Thanks man, To solve the issue, I had to recreate all my certificates,  and Worked like a magic. Thx

Comment: +1 @n0oitaf Thanks, finally I was able to debug from my other system.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to migrate your provisioning distribution certificate/key pair as described by Apple.  You can usually accomplish this by exporting on the old mac, copy over, and import.

Apple documentation describes this here:

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING_FAQ-WHAT_DOES__VALID_SIGNING_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND__MEAN_AND_HOW_DO_I_RESOLVE_IT_

You will probably need to export the keychain private key from Keychain access on your old computer which is associated to your distribution certificate.   Alternatively you can start afresh with a new key and certificate.